# Add a second authentication to user log in

Tags: ubuntu, security, authentication, profile

```
trap '' 2

code=`oathtool --base32 --totp "xxxxxxxxxxxx"`
echo -n Enter Code:
read -s password
echo ""
if [ "$password" == "$code" ]; then
        echo "You are allowed in"
else
        exit
fi

trap 2
```

Is placing this code at the top of my `.profile` another way to add two factor authentication or can this be bypassed?

I know that you can do something like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication) to add 2 factor authentication but I want to be able to customise it.

Answer (score 2):

**No!**

The basic problem is that `.profile` is only read after you are succesfully logged in! At that point a full shell is already running, and most shells are made to serve the user, *not* to stop them from doing whatever they like.

Let's see for example:

```
# echo -en "echo byebye; exit"  > ~foo/.profile
# ssh foo@localhost
foo@localhost's password: 
[...]
byebye
Connection to localhost closed.
```

But I can still tell the shell to do something completely different. (Like run another shell.)

```
# ssh foo@localhost -t "/bin/sh"
foo@localhost's password: 
$ id
uid=1001(foo) gid=1001(foo) groups=1001(foo)
```

You *could* change the user's shell to something more restricted, a program designed just to ask for the OTP and then start the shell. But that would make it hard to do anything that requires running another shell. Also, anything that is done within the user's domain, can very likely be changed back by the user, and that's not something one usually wants with authentication.

Please do the authentication where it belongs, which is PAM in most Linuxes.